# DIV with overflow:hidden lets children disappear

Tags: css, html, overflow

I have a DIV with a set height and overflow: hidden .
Inside the DIV, there's some content (a P, maybe some IMGs...   it's a wordpress post content, by the way).
The content is completely unstyled (no css applied to any of it!)

Now when I remove the height and the overflow: hidden from the DIV css, the whole content will be shown. So far, so good.
But when I set the height and the overflow-property, the content will completely disappear!! Instead of being just "cut off" at the certain height.
The DIV displays properly, but the content then seems to be completely invisible.
:(

Could you please help me if there are any errors / known problems with this method?

My HTML:

```
<div class="post-text-long">
    <?php the_content(); ?>  // This displays the post's contents, just to let you know
</div>
```

The CSS that lets the contents disappear:

```
.post-text-long {
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

EDIT: Live example removed, thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: I can't spot any obvious errors, could you post some example content?

Comment: There's no `width` specified. Is it possible some other rule has rendered this a 0-width div? In which case the overflow is hidden horizontally.

Comment: Please see my original post for a live example!

Comment: Its work well @ my machine. I simply replaced <?php the_content(); ?>  with 'Hello World' and it is showing the contents. the_content() method is echoing something?

Comment: @VoteyDiscipline - If you are not specifying any widht, in this case it will take the complete page width or couter-container's width. Checked with Mozilla 3.6 & Chrome 9

Comment: @VoteyDisciple  I think your idea worked!! There was indeed no width, adding one solved the problem!  Thank you!

Comment: @Jatin Dhoot Obviously browser defaults are to have divs span the full width of the page, but that doesn't mean there isn't another style rule overriding that setting, as appears to be the case here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
.post-text-long {
    height: 210px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
```

You need to add width to get this code working.

Comment: @bazmegakapa Thanks for editing my post... actually I'm new on stackoverflow that's why not familiar with all functionality. :)

Comment: Yep @VoteyDisciple already solved it that way, but since I can't vote a comment, I will mark your answer as the problem's solve, in case there are people with the same problem in the future :)

Comment: And I'm here to help you and edit it :). You can format your code with the `{}` button in the toolbar.

Comment: @Doom23 Thanks for the vote :) @bazmegakapa Thanks for the helping in formatting the code. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
.post-text-long { clear: left; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The html/css code is ok - http://jsfiddle.net/easwee/gXg5w/4/

You are saying that it's a wordpress content - check if there are unclosed divs or any other elements that might break your design once the content is loaded.

Open your page in firefox - if you have firebug try to delete out all html content and add in some Lorem ipsum text to see the results.

Otherwise provide a live example with problematic content.

Comment: Please see my original post for a live example!